# Нахождение суммы элементов массива целых чисел с помощью указателей

Tags: c++

Нужно найти сумму элементов массива, расположенных после нулевого
элемента массива целых чисел, с помощью указателей.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
const int n = 5;
int a[n],*p,*t, s = 0; // указатель на целое число
setlocale(0, "");
cout << "Введите массив из " << n << " элементов" << endl;
for (p = a; p - a<n; p++) cin >> *p;// Ввод элементов массива
                                    // это тоже самое что for (i=0; i<n; i++) cin>>a[i];
for (p = a; p - a<n; p++) cout << *p << " "<<endl; // Распечатка массива  
for (p = a; p - a < n; p++)
    if (*p == 0)
    {
        t = p;
        for (t = a+1; t - a < n; t++)

            s = s + *t;
    }


cout << "Сумма  элементов массива = " << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем? Просто похвастаться? :-D
Гадалка мне подсказывает, что ошибка здесь: `t = a+1`. Вроде должно быть `p+1`. Но без вопроса, как-то, исправлять вроде и неприлично..

Comment: @Vladimir хорош, спасибо вот из-за чего ошибка была:)